# shortest way to do a fetch in X86 assembler?

Tags: assembly, x86, fetch

What is the shortest way to fetch a value from memory in X86 Assembler?

Comment: What do you mean by "shortest" ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You mean other than mov register, [address]?

Comment: I just want the shortest way to get a value from memory into a CPU register.  I don't mind which way...

Comment: Assuming you're using Intel syntax you won't find a shorter or faster way than that. I'm not sure how to put this delicately... if you had to ask that question, I would strongly recommend getting a book on assembly language fundamentals before you go any further.

Answer (score 4):

There is no workaround in assembler haw to do that. **All assembler instructions are strictly dedicated.**

```
mov AL, 0x12
```

will load immediate the value 0x12 to register AL

```
xor  AL,AL
```

the result of operation in AL register is 0

```
lodsb
```

will load byte from DS:[ESI] (or DS:[SI] under 16 bit CPU) memory address to AL

```
mov AL,[ESI]
```

will load byte from DS:[ESI] (or DS:[SI] under 16 bit CPU) memory address to AL

```
mov AL,[0xFFFF]
```

will load byte from DS:[0xFFFF] memory address to AL

```
pop AX
```

will load byte from SS:[ESP] (or SS:[SP] under 16 bit CPU) memory address to AL

```
in AL, 0x123
```

will load byte from port address 0x123

```
xlatb [EBX + AL]
```

will load byte from DS:[EBX + AL] memory address

...

Answer (score 2):

OK, the shortest way is to pop registers, like `pop eax`, it's one byte instruction.
But that can be used only in special cases, where the stack pointer ESP will point to a buffer,
and probably you won't use the stack for other purpose until the code that uses it is done.

The standard way is to use the `mov` instruction.